# The Functionality of CCNode.children - Is this Redundant Code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In a rudimentary hit test function of a template I found for a cocos2d game, the original author used the following to determine which objects to preform the hit test on during the run loop.

```
for (Enemy *someEnemy in self.children) {

    if ( [someEnemy isKindOfClass:[Enemy class]] ) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Could someone elaborate on the idiosyncrasies of the list returned by .children? More specifically, is the if statement in the above code actually necessary?

Comment: Upon further thought, I believe that this may have more to do with the functionality of this particular for loop; it does not actually return only objects that are of the Enemy class, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.children` will return an array of all nodes that added as child on node.

if you add 4 children on `self`

```
 [self addChild:node1];
 [self addChild:node2];
 [self addChild:node3];
 [self addChild:node4];
```

then `children` will return these 4 nodes

```
 NSLog(@"children: %@", self.children);
```

... Your console will show the 4 children

Comment: So if I use for (OBJECT_CLASS *tempObject in self.children) {...}, it does not in fact set *tempObject to only members of the Class OBJECT_CLASS? Judging by the behavior I have been experiencing, that would seem to follow.

Comment: You are right. It will catch all array objects, it doesn't matter how class they are. If you want to check the class of object on array, you can use "if ([tempObject isKindOfClass:(TheClass class)])"